# Django filter based on request data inside perform_create

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, request

I have an API endpoint which creates an object with a specific field. I do this by using `perform_create`

```
def perform_create(self,serializer):
    group = DeviceGroup.objects.get(is_default=True, customer_uuid='some uuid')
    serializer.save(group_uuid=group)
```

When I hardcode the uuid of a customer, it works like a charm. However, I obviously do not want to hardcode an uuid in there.

The `customer_uuid` is sent in the POST request.

I tried:

- `self.kwargs['customer_uuid']`
- `self.request.customer_uuid`
- `self.request.GET['customer_uuid']`
- `self.request.GET('customer_uuid')`

How do I get the `customer_uuid` from the request?

#### EDIT

`self.request.POST.get('customer_uuid')` does not work when sending JSON in the request.

To fix this, use `self.request.data['customer_uuid']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

self.request.POST.get('customer_uuid')

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!